# All possible combinations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to find all the possible combinations in python for this problem:

```
list1 = ['M','W','D']
list2 = ['y','n']
```

What i'm looking to have is:

```
[[('M', 'y'), ('W', 'n'), ('D', 'n')], [('M', 'y'), ('D', 'n'), ('W', 'n'), ....
```

i need to have all the possibilities for M,W,D like this:

```
M W D

y n y

y y y

y y n

y n n

n y y

n n y

. . .
```

I tried:

```
import itertools
list1 = ['M','W','D']
list2 = ['y','n']
all_combinations = []
list1_permutations = itertools.permutations(list1, len(list2))
for each_permutation in list1_permutations:
    zipped = zip(each_permutation, list2)
    all_combinations.append(list(zipped))
print(all_combinations)
```

and i get:

```
[[('M', 'y'), ('W', 'n')], [('M', 'y'), ('D', 'n')], [('W', 'y'), ('M', 'n')], [('W', 'y'), ('D', 'n')], [('D', 'y'), ('M', 'n')], [('D', 'y'), ('W', 'n')]]
```

And it's absolutely not what i'm looking for as i need all the element of the list1 to be displayed into the same list and combined with the element of the list2.

I'm not sure if lists are appropriates for this problem, but what i need is all the possibilities for 'D', 'W', 'M' with 'y','n'

Comment: The first 2 elements in your example are the same with a different order. Does that really matter? According to your table example, order doesn't seem to be important

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to produce all such combinations of `list2` items with the length of `list1`, and then zip `list1` with each combination for output:

```
[list(zip(list1, c)) for c in itertools.product(list2, repeat=len(list1))]
```

This returns:

```
[[('M', 'y'), ('W', 'y'), ('D', 'y')],
 [('M', 'y'), ('W', 'y'), ('D', 'n')],
 [('M', 'y'), ('W', 'n'), ('D', 'y')],
 [('M', 'y'), ('W', 'n'), ('D', 'n')],
 [('M', 'n'), ('W', 'y'), ('D', 'y')],
 [('M', 'n'), ('W', 'y'), ('D', 'n')],
 [('M', 'n'), ('W', 'n'), ('D', 'y')],
 [('M', 'n'), ('W', 'n'), ('D', 'n')]]
```

Comment: Just finished writing exactly that solution when you posted... Well, that's then a +1 :)

Comment: You're not alone. ;)

Comment: I was about to answer but then saw your answer. +1